# Spring-Boot 1.5.10.release compatibility with apache-kafka-2.3.0 client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

My project is built with Spring boot 1.5.10.release. We want to migrate to Apache Kafka® 2.3.0 from Apache Kafka 1.0.x. 
We are currently using Spring-kafka 1.3.9.release and want to migrate to spring-kafka-2.3.0. Can we do this without changing the Spring boot version of 1.5.10.release?

I went through the Compatibility matrix but I don't see any relevant answer to my question
https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: No, you can't do that. Spring Kafka 2.x, as well Spring Boot 2.x, is based on Spring Framework 5.x and Java 8. You can't mix so critical versions in Spring Boot 1.5.x

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem. Closing this thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Spring Kafka 2.x, as well Spring Boot 2.x, is based on Spring Framework 5.x and Java 8. You can't mix so critical versions in Spring Boot 1.5.x.

It is really better to rely on the Spring Boot dependencies management. That way you can be sure that all the artifacts brought by Spring Boot are tested together.